# Jenkins Pipeline: get github commit message into vareable and keep it between agents

Tags: variables, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkins Declared Pipeline with two separate Docker containers. 
And i need to use github commit message and other git data at Post part.
Because of two different agents for two docker containers i have `agent none` at top of the pipeline.
I use some trick to get GitHub commit message. I don't know how to get it simple way.

```
environment {
            COMMIT_TEXT = sh (
            script: 'git log --format="full" -1 ${GIT_COMMIT}',
            returnStdout: true
            ).trim()
            TextComment = 'Text from Variable'
        }
```

I can't use environment with `sh` inside a top level with `agent none`,
so i need to pass variables to Past part other way.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

```
pipeline {
        agent none
/*   ---   i can not use "sh" there becouse in can not to be ececuted with 'agent none'
        environment {
            COMMIT_TEXT = sh (
            script: 'git log --format="full" -1 ${GIT_COMMIT}',
           returnStdout: true
            ).trim()
            TextComment = 'Text from Variable'
        }
*/
    stages {
        stage('build container up') {
            agent {
                docker {
                image 'container:local'
                }
/*   ---   there is no reason to put variable there, becouse it will be dead with the container before Post processing.
        environment {
            COMMIT_TEXT = sh (
            script: 'git log --format="full" -1 ${GIT_COMMIT}',
            returnStdout: true
            ).trim()
            TextComment = 'Text from Variable'
        }
*/
            }
            stages {
                stage('Build') {
                    steps{
                        git branch: 'testing-jenkinsfile', url: 'https://github.com/...git'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Build image') {
            steps {
                script {
                    docker.build("walletapi:local")
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Run service container'){
            agent {label 'master'}
            steps {
                sh 'docker run -it -d --name container01 \
                container01:local'
            }
        }
    }
}
    post {
        always {
            script {
            sh 'env'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your full pipeline script and elaborate on what you are trying to do ? Current details are not helping

Comment: Thank you @ben5556
pipeline added